# Javascript forEach changes order of FileList on images preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with image upload, you can see demo [here](https://codepen.io/ChicagoJostik/pen/jOWgVWL).
I have simple **html**:

```
<input type="file" id="files" multiple>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

When user choose images to upload, he can see a preview of what he is uploading.

My **js**:

```
$("#files").on("change", previewFiles);

function previewFiles() {
    var preview = $('.preview');
    var files   = $(this)[0].files;
  preview.empty();
    function readAndPreview(file) {

        if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name) ) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(event) {
                var conta = $('<div></div>').addClass("preview__image");

                var img = $('<img>');
                img.attr('src', event.target.result);
                img.attr('title', file.name);
                img.appendTo(conta);

                conta.appendTo( preview );
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

    }

    if (files) {
        [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
    }
  console.log(files);
    
}
```

Actually, everything is working, except an order of images that user chose in preview block.
Try to upload 10 images and open your console, you will see that `FileList` is as supposed to be, but in preview images are mixed.

I can't understand why `forEach()` is changing it.

How can I save order inside preview block? It should be the same as in `FileList`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My assumption as to why the preview is out of order is because you are adding the `conta` to the preview once the file has loaded.  `reader.onload` is asynchronous in nature, and depending upon file size, network latency (etc), they are not guarenteed to load in the same order.

Comment: You will need to consider refactoring your logic to only attempt to load the next file once the previous file has finished loading.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks, now I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onload handler you're using to pop the images into the container is asynchronous, so it just pops them in as they're loaded and not in the order in which you created them.
To get the order correct, you'll have to either use "await" or create your image containers prior to the images loading, then put those images into their respective containers as they load.